# How to filter rows with orders of special product?

Tags: mysql, sql

There is `customer` table:

```
---+-------+------------+
id + name  + region     + 
---+-------+------------+
```

There is also `orders` table:

```
---+--------------+------------+----------+----------------+
id + cusomer_id   + product    +  price   +  amount_total  +
---+--------------+------------+----------+----------------+
```

If I want to form a list of products, which have ever been bought by every customer, in a line with ';' , I make a request:

```
            SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(orders.product separator ';') 
            FROM orders
            WHERE orders.customer_id = customer.id
```

Everything work fine, however if I want to add some filters there is an error appear:

```
SELECT customers.id, 
      (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(orders.product separator ';') 
       FROM orders
       WHERE orders.customer_id = customers.id) as products 
FROM  customers        
WHERE customers.region like 'USA' 
      AND products not like '%fish%'


Query Error: Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'products' in 'where clause'
```

[db-fiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nBjpgHFVPWfJEbMjR2k9uF/20)

Comment: you cant use `products` if it is not your db column

Comment: You can only use aliases in `HAVING` clauses in MySQL. Change `AND products not like '%fish%'` to `HAVING products not like '%fish%'`

Comment: Corrected dbfiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nBjpgHFVPWfJEbMjR2k9uF/22

Comment: @Nick Perfect! Awesome! Thank you for a support!

Comment: @vppy no worries - I always try to offer the solution if I close as a dupe...

Comment: @Nick Thank you! Really supportive approach. Wish you good luck in all of your projects. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You cannot use `products` if it is not your db column you need to do like this to get it done

```
SELECT customers.id, 
      (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(orders.product separator ';') 
       FROM orders
       WHERE orders.customer_id = customers.id) as products 
FROM  customers        
WHERE customers.region like 'USA' 
      AND (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(orders.product separator ';') 
       FROM orders
       WHERE orders.customer_id = customers.id) not like '%fish%'
```

Comment: It works, thank you for your support.